# Rearrangement of an absolutely convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

Suppose I have the sequences $a_n$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges absolutely. 
Take the following rearrangement: $(a_1+a_3+....)+(a_2+a_4+....)$. The question is if that is a valid rearrangement. My problem is that I don't find a way to write this rearrangement as a function of the original arrangement.

Comment: If the series converges absolutely, then any rearrangement will converge to the same value.

Comment: This isn't a well-defined rearrangement. A rearrangement is a bijection from $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$. The ellipses imply that your pattern goes on to infinity so rather than one bijection, what you have written is two injections from $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$.

Comment: However, it is true that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges absolutely, then so do both of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k-1}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k}$, and the sum of these two latter series equals the sum of the original series. In that sense, your rearrangement is valid.

Comment: @GregMartin I don't think the sum of those two series equals the original series' in general.

Comment: If the full series converges absolutely, then yes, they do. It's a good exercise to prove this yourself, using the partial sums of all series concerned.

Comment: Here's a good reference: https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2008/05/12/commutativity-in-series-iii/